# $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ absolutely converges, $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ conditionally converges what about $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: proof-verification, improper-integrals

> $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ absolutely converges, $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ conditionally converges what can be said about $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ absolutely converges$\rightarrow$ $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges

$\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ conditionally converges $\rightarrow$ $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ converges

Because both $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ converges ,so from linearity of the improper integral (Is there linearity?)
so do $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ converges

Is it a valid proof? (it seems to be very trivial)

Comment: linearity corresponds to adding two functions, not multiplying

Comment: Does the integral converge absolutely?

Comment: @ArcticChar and if it was $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x)+g(x))dx$, it is ok to say say linearity?

Comment: @gbox Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g$ is bounded, you actually get that the integral of $fg$ is absolutely convergent. (Why?) Thus you should look to unbounded $g$ to find a possible counter-example.

Let us pick $f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\chi_{[0,1]}(x) = g(x)$, then $f(x)g(x) = x^{-1}\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$. Each of $f$ and $g$ are absolutely integrable (prove this yourself). What do you know about the integral of $fg$?

Comment: So both f(x) and g(x) converges but $f(x)*g(x)$ does not

Comment: Correct, however I would avoid using the notation $*$ as that is often used for a different mathematical operation called convolution. For multiplication if you insist on using a symbol, use $\cdot$ ($\rm\LaTeX$ command: \cdot).

Comment: the limits in the qeustion where $0$ and $\infty$, in the counterexample it is $0$ and $1$, should not we need to use the same limits?

Comment: No, you're still integrating over $[0,\infty)$. The functions just so happen to be zero outside of $[0,1]$. There's nothing wrong with that whatsoever.